# Django 1.9 pushing our code to go live today but have static directory issue

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

We are pushing our code up to go live today, and before we do I need to figure out where to put my static files. I have in the project directory a folder called static. Inside I have an admin and an image folder. When looking through the docs it looks like these should not be placed inside the actual project. But instead should be outside the project. These are the files that come with django when running the code `python manage.py collectstatic`. But for the css I have used on the site itself, it looks like I should have another folder called static, to place it all in. So my question is: Should I have a folder in my project directory called static where I house my css, and should I also have the `collectstatic` files folder, but held elsewhere?

I was told also to put my css inside a media directory. This doesnt sound correct, and I couldnt find anything in the django docs regarding static files about this.

Comment: i believe this would answer your question perfectly https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your static files in multiple folders which can reside anywhere

It will look like this in settings

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    #You can have multiple directories here
)
```

Set the STATIC_ROOT like this in settings

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

When you run `$ python manage.py collectstatic`
This will copy all files from your static folders into the STATIC_ROOT directory.

The purpose of this to gather all static files in a single directory so you can serve them easily.

**Note

Set the base directory in settings

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have to do, is to tell django STATICFILES_DIR settings where all your static folder live

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mycssfolder'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'otherstaticfolder')

]
```

so when you run djangoadmin collecstatic command it looks into all those folder for static files.